# Функционал скидок для ecommerce laravel

Tags: mysql

Есть БД с таблицей products (id,name,price). Возник вопрос: каким образом лучше делать функционал скидок на товары? Пока в голове 2 варианта:

- сделать поле discount_price и писать туда цену со скидкой.
- сделать отдельную таблицу product_discounts (id, product_id, discount_price)

Пока не могу понять, что лучше использовать в данном случае. Кто сталкивался с подобным, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: если вам надо только скидочную цену и больше ничего то будет проще будет использовать первый вариант, ну а если вы хотите прикрепить какой-то текст к акционному товару, или например акция на товар только для определенной группы пользователей то здесь подойдет второй вариант

Comment: Лучше бы описали конкретную ситуацию и ваш подход , так бы было легче ответить.Ото данный вопрос может иметь очень много решений.Одно из них: `1. Table products (id,name,price), 2.Table discounts(id,discount,start_discount, end_discount),3. Table product_discounts(id, product_id, discount_id, start_discount, end_discount, description)`.